# how to get data in 2D array in Django posted by AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

I am sending a 2D list through ajax to django

here is my function for sending ajax request

```
    var tid = $(document).find(".table-box a").data("tid")
var newFood = [];

$('#order_table td.food_name').filter(function() {
    return $(this).data('status') == 'new';
}).each(function() {
    newFood.push( [$(this).text(), $(this).siblings('.quantity').text(), $(this).siblings('.price').text()] );
});

// This will create a 2D array like this [['food_name1','1','$10.00'],['foodname2', '2', '$11.00']] 

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: $(this).data('url'),
    data: {tid:tid, newFood:newFood},
    success: function success(data){
        alert("Success")
    },
});
```

And I print the `request.POST` out in django 
and I get

```
<QueryDict: {u'tid': [u'12'], u'newFood[0][]': [u'chick noodle', u'1', u'$2.00'], u'newFood[1][]': [u'Beef Rice', u'1', u'$29.00']}>
```

when I print `request.POST.get('newFood[0][]')` , I get

```
$2.00
```

I also tried `request.POST.getlist('newFood[0]')` but I get empty list

```
[]
```

Any ideas on how to fix this? How can I retrive each item one by one?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do it.

```
        for i,j in request.POST.items():
            print i, request.POST.getlist(i)
```

And I am able to print key i = newFood[i][] and list j = ['food', 'quantity', 'price']

Answer (score 0):

This is how this was solve with me

```
for i in range(RowNum):
        data = request.GET.getlist(f'newFood[{i}][]') 
        print (data[0] +' , ' + data[1]+','+data[3])
```

where RowNum is the number of line (height) in 2d array. data[i] is the element in each line (width). I hope this will help some one

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me, Please try for individual 2d array data.

```
for i,j in request.POST.items():
        if "newFood" in i:
           dtls.append(request.POST.getlist(i))
```